# sizeWithFont returning random values

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm trying to calculate the necessary height for a cell in a tableview based on what the contents are going to be. This is in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

However, sometimes sizeWithFont is returning 0. I can't figure out how this is possible, because all the parameters are hardcoded except for one, and I can see that that parameter isn't changing.

```
NSString *address = [properties objectAtIndex:1];

CGFloat calculatedSize = [address sizeWithFont:[[UIFont alloc] fontWithSize:15.f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(207.f, 100.f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;

NSLog(@"Calculated size for %@: %f", address, calculatedSize);

calculatedSize += 19.f;

return calculatedSize;
```

This is the output if I go try this several times by going back and forth to the view several times:

```
Calculated size for 1234 Fake St: 0.000000
Calculated size for 1234 Fake St: 0.000000
Calculated size for 1234 Fake St: 0.000000
Calculated size for 1234 Fake St: 38.000000
Calculated size for 1234 Fake St: 0.000000
Calculated size for 1234 Fake St: 38.000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
[[UIFont alloc] fontWithSize:15.0f]
```

with:

```
[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.f]
```

Comment: Okay, this worked. Why? Why does `[[UIFont alloc] fontWithSize:15.f]` return variable output while `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.f]` doesn't?

Comment: First of all when you alloc an object you must init it then.. for ex. [[UIFont alloc] init], but this is not the case with the UIFont class. To create an instance of UIFont there are helper class methods like: `-fontWithName:size`, `systemFontOfSize`, etc.. For more info take a look at the [UIFont Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

i tested this and it worked

```
NSString *address = @"Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text";

CGFloat calculatedSize = [address sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0] 
                             constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(207.f, 100.f) 
                                 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;    

NSLog(@"Calculated size for %@: %f", address, calculatedSize); //String... 76.000000
```